# Whether or not we should log stack traces for HTTP 400's

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc, model-view-controller, error-handling

In a restful service implemented in Java, it's imperative to log stack traces when there's a server side error for later diagnoses and return one of the appropriate HTTP 500's code.

But what about 400's? Such examples include invalid inputs, malformed JSON/XML, authentication failure, resources not found etc. Obviously we need to log the error messages itself, but what about the stack trace? Has anyone logged these types of stack traces and found them useful or even essential?

**Edited**: 
For example (NOT limiting to this exception):

Logging just the exception itself:

```
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read JSON: Unrecognized field "foo" (class someClass), not marked as ignorable (1 known property: "bar")
 at [Source: someClass; line: 14, column: 20] (through reference chain: someClass["foo"]->someClass["bar"]->someClass["bar2"]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "foo" (class someClass), not marked as ignorable (1 known property: "bar")
 at [Source: someClass; line: 14, column: 20] (through reference chain: someClass["foo"]->someClass["bar"]->someClass["bar2"])
```

Logging the stack trace:

```
at org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.readJavaType(MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:181) ~[spring-web-3.2.11.RELEASE.jar:3.2.11.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.read(MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:173) ~[spring-web-3.2.11.RELEASE.jar:3.2.11.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.readWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.java:143) ~[spring-webmvc-3.2.11.RELEASE.jar:3.2.11.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.readWithMessageConverters(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:180) ~[spring-webmvc-3.2.11.RELEASE.jar:3.2.11.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.resolveArgument(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:95) ~[spring-webmvc-3.2.11.RELEASE.jar:3.2.11.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:77) ~[spring-web-3.2.11.RELEASE.jar:3.2.11.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:157) ~[spring-web-3.2.11.RELEASE.jar:3.2.11.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:124) ~[spring-web-3.2.11.RELEASE.jar:3.2.11.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104) ~[spring-webmvc-3.2.11.RELEASE.jar:3.2.11.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745) ~[spring-webmvc-3.2.11.RELEASE.jar:3.2.11.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:685) ~[spring-webmvc-3.2.11.RELEASE.jar:3.2.11.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80) ~[spring-webmvc-3.2.11.RELEASE.jar:3.2.11.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:919) ~[spring-webmvc-3.2.11.RELEASE.jar:3.2.11.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:851) ~[spring-webmvc-3.2.11.RELEASE.jar:3.2.11.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:953) ~[spring-webmvc-3.2.11.RELEASE.jar:3.2.11.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:855) ~[spring-webmvc-3.2.11.RELEASE.jar:3.2.11.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727) ~[servlet-api-2.5.jar:2.5]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:829) ~[spring-webmvc-3.2.11.RELEASE.jar:3.2.11.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet.service(TestDispatcherServlet.java:65) ~[spring-test-3.2.11.RELEASE.jar:3.2.11.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820) ~[servlet-api-2.5.jar:2.5]
at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain$ServletFilterProxy.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:168) ~[spring-test-3.2.11.RELEASE.jar:3.2.11.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:136) [spring-test-3.2.11.RELEASE.jar:3.2.11.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
```

Comment: What sort of stack traces are these anyway? For instance you try to deserialize JSON inputs and fail to do so?

Comment: I've provided an example.

Comment: Since this is JSON, you may want to validate it using JSON Schema before deserializing it; that would allow to not have deserialization errors, or at least greatly reduce their numbers

Answer (score 3):

I'm of the opinion that it's best to get as much context into the causing exception and log message as possible. Stacktraces can definitely be helpful, though, when dealing with complex code paths. If anything, I would just log them at a lower level than your default so they can be switched on/off when necessary.

Answer (score 1):

It might be a good idea to log the errors themselves.  This information could be of use - i.e. it would be good to know what type of client failures are occurring.  This could help you to improve the service documentation or API to make it easier for clients.

As for the specific stack traces.  It's probably not likely to be useful.  You typically know the point-of-failure (i.e. the entry point of your web service).  Thus you likely would get the same stack trace for most failures.  Although there also is no harm in logging this as well.

Answer (score 1):

You need stack traces when you *don't* know where the error is coming from. If you are deliberately logging errors yourself when you are about to deliberately reject the input with a 400, you can add something e.g. a sequence number so you can find where it came from, rather than the entire stack trace, which is really just a waste of space in this circumstance.

Answer (score 1):

I would say "no", full stack traces are not helpful for "400" errors, which generally mean something is wrong with the request, not with the server.  What would be helpful is to log as much information as possible about the offending request:  source IP and port, logged-in user (if any), offending data, partially-decoded offending data, other session variables...